# The Baer-McCoy (a.k.a. prime) radical of $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $B$ a ring and let $A$ a subring of $B$.
>
> 1. Show that $A\cap \mathrm{Nil}_{*}(B)\subset \mathrm{Nil}_{*}(A)$.
> 2. If $A$ is contained in the center of $B$, show that $A\cap \mathrm{Nil}_{*}(B)=\mathrm{Nil}_{*}(A)$.

The notation $\mathrm{Nil}_{*}(A)$ being the lower nilradical, radical of Baer-McCoy, or prime radical of $A$.
$$\mathrm{Nil}_{*}(A)=\sqrt{(0)}$$

I know that if $A$ is conmutative then equality in 2) trivially holds.

I ask for your help in section 1.

---

Could be helpful that $Nil_{*}(B)$ is the set of nilpotent elements?

Comment: Are you studying from a certain textbook?  Do you know about m-systems?

Comment: *Could be helpful that $Nil_\ast(B)$ is the set of nilpotent elements?* No, because it is *not* the set of nilpotent elements in a noncommutative ring. $M_2(\Bbb R)$ for example has a zero prime radical, but it definitely has nonzero nilpotent elements. Looking at it that way might help in the commutative case, though!

Answer (score 3):

(Hints along the path of $m$-systems, ala Manny Reyes's suggestion.)

A set $S\subset R$ is called an $m$-system if whenever $a,b\in S$, there exists $r\in R$ such that $arb\in S$.

You can check that $P$ is a prime ideal iff $R\setminus P$ is an $m$-system.

Now also along the lines of the commutative version of multiplicative systems, you can show (by the routine Zorn's Lemma argument) that an ideal maximal with respect to being disjoint from an $m$-system is a prime ideal.

So: suppose that $a\in A$ but there is a prime ideal $P\lhd A$ such that $a\notin P$. Then $A\setminus P$ is an $m$-system in $A$, *and also in $B$*. Deduce that there is a prime ideal of $B$ not containing $a$. From this, conclude that the containment you desire holds.